# CPLEX Integer infeasible column 'Ploss(1)' error

Tags: c, cplex

I will report here not the entire file (beacuse it is too large) but only the declaration of the varibles and the constraint interested.

**model.lp**

```
Subject to:
c1:    Ploss(1) - 2.06 temp(1)  = -40.376
Bounds:
 0 <= Ploss(1) <= 100000
      temp(1) = 55
Generals:
Ploss(1) temp(1)
```

**solution.sol**

```
  <variable name="Ploss(1)" index="2880" value="0"/>
  <variable name="temp(1)" index="4320" value="55"/>
```

I cannot understand why with a such easy equation CPLEX is not able to calculate the result of the variable Ploss(1)

Comment: Did you check the solution status from CPLEX? That problem is infeasible. There is no integer value of Ploss(1) that satisfies that equation.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have defined the variables Ploss(1) and temp(1) as general which mean those variables are integers/binary. In that case constraint becomes :

c1:    Ploss(1) - 2.06 * 55  = -40.376

c1:    Ploss(1)  =  113.3-40.376 = 72.924 which is not an integer. Hence this is infeasible.